# How to add nonce tag to inline script for CSP

Tags: filters

Is it possible to add nonce tag to inline scripts for wordpress sites using ?
I have used a filter script_loader_tag + function for adding tags before but it adds nonce tag only to  with src tag. Unfortunately I cant add nonce tag to inline javascript automatically :(
So I need a script for some filter which would add nonce tag automatically to  tag.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean? Do you want a nonce value available as a JS variable?

Comment: Its easy I want only one thing. Add nonce tag to inline script. Example I want have inline script <script>some script</script> and I want to add nonce tag for CSP ( Content Security Policy ) to script tag like this: <script nonce="somevalue">

Comment: WordPress has a surprising amount of inline scripts and styles. I've tried to get a CSP (Content Security Policy) ready for a WP site and have been stymied. Here's the [Trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/51325) I opened on the topic a couple versions ago.

Comment: @Macsurf As from the trac ticket @Pat J created, you can use the [`script_loader_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/) filter for the time being. If the question is reopened I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`script_loader_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/) filter:

```
function wpse_406351_script_tag_nonce( $tag, $handle ) {
    if ( $handle === 'id_of_script' /* handle used in wp_enqueue_script/wp_register_script */ ) {
        $nonce = wp_create_nonce(); // Or whatever your nonce value should be

        $tag = str_replace( '<script ', "<script nonce='$nonce' ", $tag );
    }

    return $tag;
}

add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'wpse_406351_script_tag_nonce', 10, 2 );
```